# (C#) Конвертация HTML сайта в PDF

Tags: c#, html, pdf

Как можно максимально качественно конвертировать HTML в PDF?
Есть на подобии код С#:
opf2 - open file dialog (.html)

```
var Renderer = new HtmlToPdf();
var PDF = Renderer.RenderUrlAsPdf(opf2.FileName);
PDF.SaveAs(opf2.FileName + ".pdf");
```

Использовал Using IronPdf, только потому, что видел инструкции с примерами кода для данной библиотеки, но этот способ не подходит, ибо:

1. Таблицы он не хочет конвертировать (не обрисовываются линии таблицы);
2. Не хочет переворачивать текст на 90 градусов;
3. Не подгружает внешние картинки страницы.

Больше рабочих библиотек с нормальными примерами я не видел... Так же конвертеры онлайн работают по такому же принципу. Единственный нормальный конвертер оказался браузер в раздели печати ("Сохранить в PDF"). 
Какие вы можете предложить конвертеры (с примером кода), которые могут справится с данной задачей?

> Перед тем как поставить sage посту, убедительно прошу написать причину данного решения опытных людей, чтобы в дальнейшем не допускать таких ошибок!

Comment: [Convert HTML to PDF in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/564650/312041)

Comment: @tym32167 Я инструкцию для работы с wkhtmltopdf в С# нашёл с таким текстом:
"wkhtmltopdf - бесплатный инструмент, но он не написан в .NET, и его можно было бы сложно интегрировать в ваше приложение asp.net."

Comment: [This is a small C# wrapper utility around wkhtmltopdf console tool. You can use it to easily convert HTML reports to PDF.](https://github.com/codaxy/wkhtmltopdf)

Comment: Я недавно перепробовал много библиотек для конвертации, лучшей оказалась SelectPdf . Но она уусловно бесплатная - не более 5 страниц. У остальных были изъяны - то отступы неправильные, то внешние картинки. Ещё рекомендую HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp посмотреть

Comment: @vusaldev на данный момент я из твоего списка попробовал SelectPdf, по факту всё работает, кроме горизонтального текста и картинок (.SVG)... Эта тема пофиксится, если я куплю лицензию?

Comment: Вряд ли, в ограничениях только 5 страниц фигурирует. Значит другое не работает или надо костыли. Я в своё время просто брал этот вопрос и чекал все варианты от самого популярного к менее популярному. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net